# Upload image to a folder

Tags: php, web-services, mysqli

In my localhost image is uploading to folder and path is saved in database, It is working in local server but on godaddy server it is saving path in database but not uploading image into a folder. Give suggestion how can I solve this..

```
$temp = explode(".",$_FILES['company_logo']['name']); 
$newfilename = rand(1,999999999) . '.' .end($temp); 
$source=$_FILES['company_logo']['tmp_name']; 
$destination='images/'.$newfilename; 
@move_uploaded_file( $source , $destination );
$query2="insert into zoho_customers (company_logo)values('$destination')";
$res2=mysqli_query($con,$query2)or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

where company_logo specified as below

```
<input type="file" name="company_logo"/>
```

Comment: give the folder permission on server to upload images.

Comment: can you please share any link that can help me out

Comment: Pleas show your code...

Comment: see above for code

Comment: Search "file permissions godaddy hosting" and you should find some answers, it's almost certainly a permissions problem. PHP is generally run as a limited user so it can't go haywire, you'll need to explicitly `chmod +777` or similar a file or directory to give your script permission to write to it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is destination $destination contain the image file.

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["company_logo"]["tmp_name"], "images/" . $_FILES["company_logo"]["name"]);

You can get a clear idea here 
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp